# one liner to go through an iterable (generator)

Tags: python, one-liner

I encountered some code looking like:

```
[func(val) for val in iterable]
```

There is an iterable (in my case a generator) for which a user wants to call a function for each value for its side effects (`func` could for example just be `print`) but where the return value is irrelevant.

What I don't like about this approach is, that a temporary `list` is created, which might consume quite some memory if the generator yields a lot of values.

If the return value of `func` always evaluates to `False`, then following works:

```
any(func(val) for val in iterable)
```

If the return value of func always evaluates to `True`, then following works:

```
all(func(val) for val in iterable)
```

What would I have to do if the return value of func can evaluate to `True` or to `False`

Anything better then forcing the value to False?

The best I came up with is:

```
any(func(val) and False for val in iterable)
```

or

```
all(func(val) or True for val in iterable)
```

Comment: Could you maybe clarify or give an example of the expected output/result? If is maily the memory you are afraid of, just use `(func(val) for val in iterable)` which is a constructor that only yields the result when asked, thus all the answers are not held in memory when initiated.

Comment: In fact the person did not want to write a two line:

`for val in iterable():` followed by `func(val)`

He wanted to write an elegant and fast performing way of calling a function for each member of an iterable and used a list expression.

SO her looking for a one liner (ideally) an expression, that calls a funciton for each member of an iterable, but doesn't bild a list for nothing

Comment: not sure if this is true (too lazy to uncompile and compare), but I have the impression, that
a `for` statement is slightly less performant than using `any` or `all`, but I'm not 100% sure about this.

I encountered above code and was curious about the best way to improve it (mem and performance wise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just

```py
for val in iterable:
   func(val)
```

is clearest.

```py
for val in iterable: func(val)
```

is available if a one-liner is truly necessary.

Comment: agreed, but that's a two liner. I wanted to suggest another one liner to the person who wrote the one liner with a list.

Comment: Yep, just after commenting I remembered , that `for` can be a one liner

Comment: You could hide that `for` loop in a function somewhere.  I.e., `def exhaustIterable(iterable): ...`

Comment: for as one liner is OK. I  was more wondering whether there is already something builtin, that behaves like your suggested `exhaustIterable`

Comment: will probably accept this answer. only minor draw back is, that it cannot be used as a `lambda`, as it is not an expression, but a statement,

But this was not part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `set` with `bool` function?

```py
{bool(func(val)) for val in iterable}
```

**EDITED:**
After looking at @gelonida's analysis, I believe the following is a bit faster.

```py
{None for val in iterable(N) if func(val)}
```

Comment: Yep second solution is better. It avoids determining the hash of `func`'s return values.

Your second solution gave me an alternative idea:
`[None for val in iterable(N) if func(val) and False]` but is not more performant than your solution and not more readable

Answer (score 1):

Just a synthesis and timing analysis of the given answers /  potential solutions

It seems that @LeopardShark's answer is the shortest, most readable answer.
and amongst the fastest. (timeit is not exact and I didn't look at the byte codes)

Speed wise 
 - @LeopardShark's answer
 - @ywbaek's second suggestion 
 - The initial code, that I found if N is not too big (~10000) 
 - the suggestions, that I posted in my question

The initial code has the drawback of allocating releasing memory for nothing.

The code I suggested in my question has the drawback to be less intuitive to understand and if messing up the combination of (`all`, `any`) and (`and False`, `or True`) one might not execute everything as expected and is also a little less performant

@ywbaek's solution is safer than my suggestions and about as intuitive, but is executing a little faster.

The simplest solution has the minor drawback of not being usable as lambda.

My code for timing:

```
N=10000
M=500

called = 0
def func(v):
    global called
    called += 1
    v * v * v * v * v *v / (v+0.1)

def iterable(N):
    for v in range(N):
        v * 2
        yield v

def testrun():
    global called
    called=0
    print(timeit(test, number=M), end=" ")
    print(called)

print("consume some CPU")
timeit(lambda: 3**.5 **.2) # it seems, that timeit is a little more predictable if I let the process warm up a little

print("Start measures")

def test():
    for val in iterable(N): func(val)
testrun()

def test():
    {None for val in iterable(N) if func(val)}
testrun()

def test():
    [func(val) for val in iterable(N)]
testrun()

def test():
    all(func(val) or True for val in iterable(N))
testrun()

def test():
    any(func(val) and False for val in iterable(N))
testrun()
```

results on my old PC:

```
consume some CPU
Start measures
3.864932143012993 5000000
3.916696268017404 5000000
4.0817033689818345 5000000
4.293206526956055 5000000
4.319622751965653 5000000
```